# String is an undeclared type?

Tags: swift

In the example below, the extension function has an undeclared parameter type. `String`.  Huh? How is that an undeclared type?

```
import UIKit

enum ColumnType: String {
    case StringArray
    , IntArray
    , DoubleArray
    , String = "text"
    , Int = "int"
    , Double = "double"
    , Unknown
}

extension ColumnType {
    func fromRaw(rawValue: String) -> ColumnType {
        if let valueType = ColumnType(rawValue: rawValue) {
            return valueType
        }

        switch rawValue {
        case "text", "Text":
            return .String
        case "int", "Int":
            return .Int
        case "double", "Double":
            return .Double
        default:
            return .Unknown
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the down vote on a legitimate question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within `ColumnType` (which you are, because this is an extension, `String` is `ColumnType.String`, not `Swift.String`. I'd highly recommend against redefining stdlib types like this, but if you must, you can refer to the Swift type using the `Swift` package:

```
func fromRaw(rawValue: Swift.String) -> ColumnType {
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can rename `ColumnType.String` to something else to avoid the name collision.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks Rob.